# How do I store a jquery object on a HTML element property?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<select>` form element where I create multiple `<option>` children based on looping through a jQuery array of objects.

I want to store each jQuery associated with an `<option>` on the `<option>` itself, I guess as a property. So that when I get the change event fired I can pull out the jQuery object which the `<option>` was based on.

I thought I could just set it using attr, serializing the object into JSON, but its not working. Any ideas?

Here is some code:

```
// creating the select: (data is a jquery array of objects)
    $(data).each(function() {
        var opt = $('<option></option>').val(this[id_property]).html(this[label_property]);
        // preserve the original jquery object on this <option> element:
        opt.attr('json', JSON.stringify(this));
        $(select).append(opt);
    });

// bind the onchange event, and try to recreate that original jquery object
    $(select).bind('change', function(event) {
        // this gives me a ref to the <option> element:
        var val = $(select).find(":selected");
        // now how to get the original jquery object?
        var item = $(val).attr('json');        
    });
```

I want that last line setting var item to the original jquery object - or somehow recreate it. I even tried doing an `eval()` passing in item since it is JSON formatted but it throws an error.

Comment: The reverse of `JSON.stringify` is `JSON.parse`.

Comment: Don't use the `jQuery` wrapper for non-DOM-objects like your `data`. It is slow and might have side effects. To iterate it, use for-loops or `jQuery.each` if you need a callback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take advantage of the [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) method in jQuery, this will likely yield you the most favorable results as well as giving you the ability to avoid unnecessary custom serialization.

Comment: @trant *In other words, you won't need `JSON.stringify` if you use `.data()` to store and retreive the object*